# Is it possible to add spotify widget in my mobile application?

Tags: android, spotify

I am building a mobile application using android. Client requirement is to add spotify in a activity.
Is it really possible? if not why? if yes how?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/content-linking-guide/ or https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes i have seen it already but this doesnt meet my need unfortunately :/